# Unable to access uploaded file in browser through URL in Lumen

Tags: php, nginx, filesystems, flysystem, lumen-5.4

I'm building a web app with Docker, Nginx and Lumen. I have completed file upload functionality and everything works fine. However, when I try to access uploaded file from URL Lumen throws me `NotFoundHttpException`.

I have already created symlink between storage and public folders using the following command:

```
    ln -s /var/www/storage/app/public /var/www/public/storage
```

This is my Nginx configuration:

```
    http {
        index index.html index.php;
        sendfile on;
        tcp_nopush on;
        gzip on;
        gzip_proxied any;
        gzip_types text/plain text/css text/xml text/javascript application/x-javascript application/xml;
        gzip_vary on;
        gzip_disable "msie6";

        server {
            disable_symlinks off;
            listen 80;
            listen [::]:80;
            server_name api.uhire.test www.api.uhire.test;
            root /var/www/public;

            location / {
                try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php?$query_string;
            }

            location ~ \.php$ {
                fastcgi_split_path_info ^(.+\.php)(/.+)$;
                fastcgi_pass php:9000;
                fastcgi_index index.php;
                include fastcgi_params;
                fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
                fastcgi_param PATH_INFO $fastcgi_path_info;
            }
        }
    }
```

My file's path is `storage/app/public/customers/1/test.jpeg`. However, this is not accessible if I type `http://api.uhire.test/storage/customers/1/test.jpeg` in browser's URL bar.